# Chrome CSS Class selector issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, path, inspector

I'm having a problem with how Chrome inspector generates CSS .class paths.

When I add a style rule for a class I want ".classname" instead of (for example) "body > div.classname". See the attached images.

I can't seem to find any options in the inspector property panel to disable this. Any tips?

Comment: Chrome allows you to specify using `.classname` if you want when you use the inspector.  I don't see the problem here.  Also, I think you forgot the images.

Comment: If you can't use images, just use hyperlinks.  Also, I still don't see your example.

Comment: stackoverflow wouldn't let me upload any images until I reached a reputation af 10 points or more. Anyhow, the thing is that I would like the inspector to use paths like ff firebug does. I've uploaded an example here:

http://andreasnorberg.net/hemsideexempel/chrome/

Comment: I still see no problem.  You should probably read up on chrome developer tools for how to properly use it: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I probably should, but it seems that this guy is experiencing the same problem:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=347015

Comment: You just need to do the exact same thing that you do in firefox.  You literally just type the class into the spot where it allows you to.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I want chrome inspector to generate ".song" instead of "body > div.musikwrapper.blue > div:nth-child(2)" when I click "+ / new style rule", just like Firefox Firebug does. So I dont need to type it in manually. 

It's not a big issue, it would just smoothen the workflow a bit.

Comment: Oh.  There may be some functionality for that in Chrome that I'm not aware of.  You could try looking in settings, but as you said, it's not really that big of an issue.  That's the purpose of them highlighting that text when you add it (so you can change it to what you want).